# React native Flatlist blank area on android 6 version and below

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Flatlist have 600 items, I use horizontal views like pages
I test on android pie and work well, on android 6 marshmallow has a lot blank areas.
I try with initialNumToRender ,maxToRenderPerBatch, updateCellsBatchingPerio and windowSize and I didn't get desire results. I also use animated.view for header and footer. Is there some solution for large flatlist or some other solution for large viewpager for android and ios.

```
  getItemLayout = (data, index) => (
     {length: WIDTH, offset: WIDTH * index, index}
   )

  renderItem1=({item}) => {
     return(
       <View style={styles.container} key={item.key}>
           {Object.values(item)[0].map((it, key) => {
           return key == 0 ?
               <TouchableOpacity key={key} activeOpacity={1} style= . 
      {styles.imageView} onPress= 
     .{this.showHeaderFooter}>
     <Image style={{ width: IMGWIDTH, height: IMGHEIGHT }} source= . 
      {it.url} />
               </TouchableOpacity>
      : null
      })
     }
        </View>
    )}

    <FlatList
          onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged }
          viewabilityConfig={{
            itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50
          }}
          data={data1}
          horizontal={true}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          extraData={this.state}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          removeClippedSubviews={false}
          initialNumToRender={600}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={60}
          updateCellsBatchingPeriod={150}
          windowSize={21}
          legacyImplementation={false}
          initialScrollIndex={this.state.numPage}
          getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
          pagingEnabled={true}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of React Native are you using? I'm having a similar problem on React Native > 60 on Android, but it's fine on IOS and it's fine on React Native < 60 on Android. For now I'm continuing to use React Native < 60 but that's not really a good solution since it limits what I can do with dependencies. I will edit this if I find a better answer.

Comment: i use Rn version 60, it only don't work on android version 6 and below.

Comment: I figured out my problem. I'm not sure if it's the same thing that's causing your problem. Apparently flex behaves a little differently on RN android 60 and above than it did in earlier versions of RN. Here is a link to my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58107627/9147743  I hope that helps!